# text automatically resizes without media queries (responsive design)

Tags: css, text, resize, media-queries

Is there a way to have a text automatically resized , depending on browser or screen or text's container? (not depending on device, because is not a good practice).

And without the help of CSS 3 media queries! It would be awesome not to use media queries because the code will be less and usally you have to use fallbacking for older browsers to understand media queries.

I know there is a way for setting a [relative size](http://alistapart.com/article/fluidgrids), but how about a size that will auto-resize? I tried `font-size:auto;` and `font-size:120%` but if I stretch down my browser's window the size is the same.

Comment: give a try to `em` something like: `font-size: 1.5em`

Answer (score 5):

1. You can use vw and vh which resize relatively to the viewport:

   ```
   1vw = 1% of viewport width
   1vh = 1% of viewport height
   1vmin = 1vw or 1vh, whichever is smaller
   1vmax = 1vw or 1vh, whichever is larger
   ```

   http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/
2. You can use JavaScript:
   e.g: http://fittextjs.com/

Answer (score -2):

Instead of px use Rem,
here are few scales to use instead of px:

| px | rem |
| --- | --- |
| 1 px | 0.0625 rem |
| 2 px | 0.125 rem |
| 3 px | 0.1875 rem |
| 4 px | 0.25 rem |
| ... | ... |
| 9 px | 0.5625 rem |
| 10 px | 0.625 rem |
| 11 px | 0.6875 rem |
| 12 px | 0.75 rem |
| 13 px | 0.8125 rem |

for more refer to https://www.pixelconverter.com/pixel-to-rem-converter/

Comment: It doesn't answer the question. And is not correct either. For my granny, who uses large default fonts in their browser, 12px will be 0.6rem, not 0.75rem as you stated above.

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros   The value of rem depends upon base value of pixel . above i had used base value 16 .  Maybe your granny is using base value 20 , thats why it will be 0.6 . fir example  if pixel in your work is 12 and base size is 20, and you want to convert px to rem manually: Rem=12/20=0.6  .  Usually the base size used nowadays is 16 .

Comment: Thanks, I know all that, I've been working with CSS way too long :) It doesn't change the fact that your answer is incorrect.